# Can't subtract 1 from bank

Tags: java, subtraction

PS: the links you have to take out the () from http because I don't have enough rep points or something.

Board:

```
package game;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
Turn_Ticker turn = new Turn_Ticker();
Bank bank = new Bank();
Image Background;
Timer timer;
String time="";
public Board() {
    setFocusable(true);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("res/Level1.png"); // calls image for     background
    Background = icon.getImage(); // sets variable background to icon image
    timer = new Timer(5,this); // sets how fast page refreshes
    timer.start();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { // Refreshes page according to timer 
    repaint();
}
public void paint(Graphics paint) { // paints on frame
    super.paint(paint);
    Graphics2D p = (Graphics2D) paint;
    turn.getTick();
    bank.subBank();
    p.drawImage(Background, 0, 0, null);
    p.drawString(bank.getBank()+"",125,70);
    p.drawString(bank.getEnemy_Bank()+"",125,115);
    p.drawString(turn.getSecond()+" Second(s)                                       Turn: "+turn.getTurn(), 120, 200);
    if(turn.getTick())
        p.drawString("Ticker = true", 500,500);/*
    if(turn.getNum()==0)
        p.drawString("Number = 0", 500,550);
    if(turn.getNum()==0&&turn.getTick()){
        bank.subBank();
        p.drawString("Both are =", 500, 600);
    }*/

    //System.out.println("X: "+mouse.getX()+" Y: "+mouse.getY());
}   
}
```

Turn_Ticker:

```
package game;

public class Turn_Ticker {
long before,after,difference;
boolean checkTime=true;
int seconds=0;
boolean ticker=false;
int turn=1;
int num=0;
public Turn_Ticker(){
    if (checkTime == true)
        before=System.currentTimeMillis();
    checkTime=false;        
}
public int getSecond() {
    after=System.currentTimeMillis();       
    difference= after-before;   

    if(difference >= 1000) {
        before=System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(seconds<=0) {
            seconds=30;
            ticker=true;
            num=0;              
        }
        else {
            seconds-=1;
            num=1;
            ticker=false;
        }
    }   
    return seconds;
}
public boolean getTick() {
    if(ticker&&num==0) { 
        turn++;
    }           
    return ticker;
}
public int getNum(){
    return num;
}
public int getTurn() {
    return turn;
}
public boolean getTickVar(){
    return ticker;
}
}
```

Bank:

```
package game;

public class Bank {
Turn_Ticker turn = new Turn_Ticker();
int bank=5, enemy_Bank=5;
int baseRein=3, reinforcements,num=0;
public Bank(){
    if(turn.getTick()==false)
        num=0;
}
public int getBank(){
    return bank;
}
public int getEnemy_Bank(){
    return enemy_Bank;
}
public void subBank(){
    if(turn.getNum()==0&&turn.getTick())
        bank--;
}
public void subEn_Bank(){
    enemy_Bank-=1;
}

}
```

Frame:

```
package game;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Frame {
public Frame() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new Board());
    frame.setTitle("WSMD");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1024,768);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}   
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Frame();
}

}
```

My problem is that I can not, for the life of me, figure out why it won't subtract `-1(bank.subBank())` from the bank. I've printed out the code and went through it step by step.

Comment: It would be better if you post your code instead of links, don't worry about formatting it there will be people that can handle it (note: format it for you doesn't mean **indent the code for you**). Also, explain the specific problem you have to do this.

Comment: have you tried debugging it?

Comment: If the method isn't decrementing `bank` then it's probably because the guard condition is never met. Put a breakpoint on `if(turn.getNum()==0&&turn.getTick())` to see why the guard condition isn't being met.

Comment: Public void subBank() method of your Bank class, create breakpoint at Line 18 and debug and observe values, i am doubt the if block is not executing,

Comment: I ran through the debugger and the guard condition is met but when it goes to check the condition the boolean ticker becomes false.